# Add rows dynamically to HTML table in MVC using HTML Tag Helpers

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Let me setup some background for my question. I am building an asp.net core mvc application with a model similar to below

```
public class Employee {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ExpertLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Now I don't want a separate page for adding `Skills`. So in my view (create, edit, etc) for `Employee`, I want to represent the `List<Skill>` as an HTML Table. Now below the table I have couple of buttons that I will use to `Add Skill` and `Remove Skill`. Relevant portion of my cshtml looks like below

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Skills.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Skills.ExpertLevel)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Skills != null) {
            @foreach (var item in Model.Skills) {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for=@item.Name />
                        <span asp-validation-for=@item.Name class="text-danger" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpertLevel)
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for=@item.ExpertLevel />
                        <span asp-validation-for=@item.ExpertLevel class="text-danger" />
                    </td>
                </tr>}
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

This razor code gets transformed into html like below

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Skill</th>
            <th>ExpertLevel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                C#
                <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="Skill Name is required" id="item_Name" name="item.Name" value="C#" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="item.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </td>
            <td>
                Yes
                <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExpertLevel must be a number." id="item_ExpertLevel" name="item.ExpertLevel" value="4.0" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="item.ExpertLevel" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Now, I have already worked out how to add the rows and delete the rows using javascript, except that I use plain html to construct the row on the fly (something like below).

```
var tdStr = '';
$(rowId).children('td').each(function () {
    tdStr += '<td>' + $.trim($(this).children().first().val()) + '</td>';
});

var tr = $('<tr>' + tdStr + '</tr>');
$(tableId + ' > tbody:last-child').append(tr);
```

I don't like that I have to manually create the tags with all the relevant attribute like data-val-required, class="text-danger field-validation-valid", etc. The tag helpers will really help me to improve the quality of my code.

My question is how can I "build" my table rows without having to hard-code my model DataAnnotations information (like RequiredAttribute.ErrorMessage, DataTypeAttribute, etc) and other such information which the tag helper infers from the `Linq.Expression`,  into the javascript

I was playing with the `template` tag or "hidden tr" but could not make much headway.

I am very new to asp.net core, mvc, html and javascript. I am using this project to learn these technologies and the right practices.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could clone a template record like this:

```
<table id="TheTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Skill</th>
            <th>ExpertLevel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr id="example">
            <td>
                <span data-template-field="fieldA">C#</span>
                <input  type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="Skill Name is required" id="item_Name" name="item.Name" value="C#" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="item.Name" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-template-field="fieldB">Yes</span>
                <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ExpertLevel must be a number." id="item_ExpertLevel" name="item.ExpertLevel" value="4.0" />
                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="item.ExpertLevel" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>

<button onclick="addLine('#TheTable')">add line</button>
```

and javascript code:

```
addLine = function(tableId)
{
    var templaterow = $('#example');
    var clone = templaterow.clone(true)[0];    

    var fieldA = clone.querySelector('[data-template-field="fieldA"]');
    var fieldB = clone.querySelector('[data-template-field="fieldB"]');

    fieldA.innerText = "<new value>";
    fieldB.innerText = "123";

    $(tableId + ' > tbody:last-child').append(clone);   
}
```

How you make the example record is up to you.
You could use the first row, but then you will have a problem if you have an empty table, so I suppose it is better to add an invisible table with just one row containing a dummy record, just so you have the layout. Then hide that table.

good luck

(PS: example uses jQuery https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js)